# Count keys in an array having same values in a row

Tags: php, arrays

For example I have this array:

```
array(
[0] => 'a',
[1] => 'b',
[2] => 'c',
[3] => 'b',
[4] => 'b',
[5] => 'b'
);
```

Is there an elegant way to understand that the latest 3 keys have `'b'` in a row?
Thanks for any suggestion

Comment: What do you mean by 'understand'?

Comment: I mean "counting" them as the title says

Comment: Write a loop, and set a variable to the last value. Then check if the current value is the same, and increment the counter.

Comment: What kind of result do you want from this?

Comment: You should find out ASCII value of b and check using for or while loop.

Comment: What does ASCII have to do with it? Just compare strings with `=`.

Comment: @Barmar I asked for an elegant way, such as a built in function/s. I know how to do it with a loop, just would like to avoid the old style way.

Comment: If you're looking for something built into PHP, I think you're out of luck. It has `array_count_values()`, but it's not for consecutive values.

Comment: I think you have got your answer by edtheprogrammerguy and others but you are teasing us

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$array = ["3","3","a","b","a"];
$count_array = array();
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    if(!in_array($value,$count_array)) {
        $count_array[$value][] = $key;
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
echo nl2br(print_r($count_array,true));
echo "</pre>";

foreach($count_array as $key => $value) {
echo $key . ":" . count($value)  . "<br>";
}
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0

        [1] => 1
    )
[a] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2
        [1] => 4
    )
[b] => Array
    (
        [0] => 3
    )
 )
3:2
a:2
b:1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you consider a official-php-function as elegant, I don't think you will find one. But you could always do it your self like this:

```
function elegantCountWhatEver($array) {
    $counts =  array();
    $count = 0;
    $last = "";
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        if($value != $last) {
            array_push($counts, array($count, $last));
            $count = 0;
            $last = $value;
        }
      $count++;
    }
    array_shift($counts);
    array_push($counts, array($count, $value));
    return $counts;
}
```

This would return an array like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => a
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => b
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => c
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 3
        [1] => b
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out and then loop the `$redundant` array and display as you please:

```
<?php
$list = array('a','b','c','b','b','b','f','f','f','2','2','2','2','f','f');

$last_val = false;

$redundant = array();

$i = 0;

foreach($list as $k=>$v)
{
    if($last_val === $v)
    {
        if(isset($redundant[$i][$v]))
        {
            $redundant[$i][$v] += 1;
        }
        else
        {
            $redundant[$i][$v] = 2;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $last_val = $v;
        $i++;
    }
}

echo '<pre>'.print_r($redundant, true).'</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: Are you looking to group the occurrences or keep them separate? My current example will show an f repeating 3 times and then again 2 times. Are you looking to just show a total of 5 with the example array I did?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for an elegant way.
If it is about doing it with a loop I already did it with few lines of code. But I still do not like this a lot :D

```
$consec_red = 0;
$consec_black = 0;
$last_found = null;
$spins = array_reverse($spins);

foreach ($spins as $spin => $type) {
    if($consec_red  == 0 && $consec_black == 0)
        $last_found = $type;
    if ($type == 'red' && $last_found == 'red')
        $consec_red++;
    elseif ($type == 'black' && $last_found == 'black')
        $consec_black++;
    else
        break;
}
```

Comment: Wrap it in a function, give it an elegant name.